# CSS not loading in Laravel's blade (5.3)

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.3

This is my blade view:

```
@extends('emails.newlayout')

@section('title', 'Reminder')

@section('content')
<?php $total = 0; ?>         
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Amount</th> 
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody> 
@foreach ($sallary as $emp)
<tr>
<td>{{ $emp->employee['name'] }}</td>
<td>{{ $emp['value'] }}</td>
<?php $total += $emp['value']; ?>
</tr> 
@endforeach
</tbody> 
</table>
<p>Total: US${{ $total }}</p>
@stop
```

And this is within the header of my newlayout.blade.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Works just fine on my browser when I open it as html, but when I render it on laravel it just doesn't load the bootstrap css at all (loads everything else). I wonder what am I doing wrong?

**OUTPUT**

[image]

```
<table class="m_-7473167048951624218table m_-7473167048951624218table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th> 
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody> 
<tr>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>1,093.55</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Test 3</td>
<td>1,090.33</td>
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: What is the output you got after rendering it on laravel?

Comment: Everything it should, *except* the table styling, which was supposed to load from bootstrap.

Comment: What is - provide the **Exact** output

Comment: Added to the post **EDIT** there's css inside the html file, this is the table's code: `table { font-size: 14px; border: 0px }` is it blocking bootstrap one?

Comment: This is a printscreen, not the output

Comment: I get it now, it's butchering my code for some reason. this is the table its outputting: `<table class="m_-7473167048951624218table m_-7473167048951624218table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Value</th> 
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody> 
<tr>
<td>Test 2</td>
<td>1,093.55</td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td>Test 3</td>
<td>1,090.33</td>
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>` look at the class.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it**

Embarrassing, but turns out it's because of e-mail. Every style should be inline css on an email, otherwise it doesn't render well according to a plethora of documentation about styling mails online.